# Zend framework _redirect url stays the same

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to redirect with Zend framework but something really strange happens what I just can't understand.

At first you are at `token.phtml`, the `loginform` action looks like this:

```
<?php print $this->url(array('controller' => 'login', 'action' => 'login'));?>"
```

In the `loginAction` I'm checking if a user exists or not. When an user is not found I want it to stay at `token.phtml` so I do this:

```
$this->_redirect('/login/token');
```

But the URL changes to the URL like you where logged in also if I do view page source in Firefox it shows the source of the logged on page.

But it does go to `token.phtml` because it outputs the `<div>`'s and everything just fine.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.  Could you please post some or all of your code for loginAction() in IndexController.php so we can see what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

change your way: if bad login stay in same page ad show message error and if login right, redirect where you want:
try to change your action controller so:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $form = new Form_Login();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
        //stuff check login
        $loginResult = //call method check, if bad return message error

        if (true === $loginResult) {
            //login success redirect where you want
            $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
        } else {
            // auth failed
            foreach ($loginResult as $field => $message) {
                $form->getElement($field)->addError($message);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Comment: The same issue as here down below, now the url stays at token.phtml when a user is found als the source is the same but the html output not

Answer (score 0):

try to leave form action empty, so you'll get the request in tokenAction. In tokenAction check if user exist and all that stuff, then if true redirect to login action

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute(
                array(
                   // route like:
                       'controller' => 'login'
                       'action' => 'login'
                    ), 
                'routenameifyouwant'
            );
```

Comment: i tried this but now it the url stays at token.phtml and the source is also from token.phtml but the html output is login when user is found

Answer (score 0):

Apparently jquery mobile is causing this problem.
jquery mobile submits its forms via AJAX automatically, if i turn AJAX off the URL changes correctly and so does the source.